# Laravel 6 Remember me token error on user login

Tags: php, laravel, authentication, laravel-6, remember-me

How to implement remember me in laravel 6 login

So far I have done this following laravel 6 documentation.

**In my Users table I have a column called remember_token to store the value.**

This is my login controller,

```
public function login(Request $request,$remember)
    {   
        $input = $request->all();

        $this->validate($request, [
            'email' => 'required',
            'password' => 'required',
        ]);

        $fieldType = filter_var($request->email, FILTER_VALIDATE_EMAIL) ? 'username' : 'username';
        if(auth()->attempt(array($fieldType => $input['email'], 'password' => $input['password'],$remember)))
        {
            return redirect()->route('home');
        }else{
            return redirect()->route('login')
                ->withFail(__('sentence.Login failed due to invalid credentials.'),'Email-Address And Password Are Wrong.');
        }

    }
```

And my login form as follows,

```
<form method="POST" action="{{ route('login') }}">
                        @csrf

                        <div class="form-group row">
                            <label for="email" class="col-md-4 col-form-label text-md-right">{{ __('sentence.Username') }}</label>

                            <div class="col-md-6">
                                <input id="email" type="text" class="form-control @error('email') is-invalid @enderror" name="email" value="{{ old('email') }}"  autocomplete="email" autofocus>
                                @error('email')
                                    <span class="invalid-feedback" role="alert">
                                        <strong>{{ $message }}</strong>
                                    </span>
                                @enderror
                            </div>
                        </div>

                        <!-- <p>{{ trans('sentence.welcome')}}</p> -->
                        <!-- {{ __('sentence.welcome') }} -->

                        <div class="form-group row">
                            <label for="password" class="col-md-4 col-form-label text-md-right">{{ __('sentence.Password') }}</label>

                            <div class="col-md-6">
                                <input id="password" type="password" class="form-control @error('password') is-invalid @enderror" name="password"  autocomplete="current-password">

                                @error('password')
                                    <span class="invalid-feedback" role="alert">
                                        <strong>{{ $message }}</strong>
                                    </span>
                                @enderror
                            </div>
                        </div>

                        <div class="form-group row">
                            <div class="col-md-6 offset-md-4">
                                <div class="form-check">
                                    <input class="form-check-input" type="checkbox" name="remember" id="remember" {{ old('remember') ? 'checked' : '' }}>

                                    <label class="form-check-label" for="remember">
                                        {{ __('sentence.Remember Me') }}
                                    </label>
                                </div>
                            </div>
                        </div>

                        <div class="form-group row mb-0">
                            <div class="col-md-8 offset-md-4">
                                <button type="submit" class="btn btn-primary">
                                    {{ __('sentence.Login') }}
                                </button>

                                @if (Route::has('password.request'))
                                    <a class="btn btn-link" href="{{ route('password.request') }}">
                                        {{ __('sentence.Forgot Your Password?') }}
                                    </a>
                                @endif
                            </div>
                        </div>
                    </form>
```

but the mentioned code giving me following error,

**Symfony\Component\Debug\Exception\FatalThrowableError
Too few arguments to function App\Http\Controllers\Auth\LoginController::login(), 1 passed and exactly 2 expected**

Comment: why is there a `$remember` parameter? Cant you just have `$request->post('remember_me')` (or whichever name is being used)?

Comment: it has inserted the value now, but once i log out the value remains the same? is that okay? what is the main purpose of having a remember me function?